# How to know the linked Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet (Master Sheet) which is linked to many other google sheets using `importrange` to know the live data. Due to this import live data my sheets got crashed and the data in my Master Sheet also huge in size(>250 MB). It looks like it has been connected to multiple worksheets.

But how do I know which sheets or sheets count are getting linked to my Original master sheet?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Extract the forumlae out the master sheet and extract the IDs of the other Spreadsheets.*

#### Workflow and Code:

You'll have to make this a standalone script project if your master sheet is crashing, but what you need to do is something like:

- Open the master sheet by ID
- For each sheet, extract all formulae and push them to an array
- Flatten the array to remove empty cells
- Extract only formulae that contain 'importrange'

The last line of this then saves a list of the `importrange`s to a `txt` file in Drive, but you can process this as you like.

**Remember:** this *may* take a while if your Sheet is very large.

```js
function getFormulae() {
  var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheetId);
  var importRangeFormulae = [];
  
  masterSheet.getSheets().forEach(function (sheet) {
    sheet.getDataRange().getFormulas().forEach(function (inner) {
      importRangeFormulae.push(inner.filter(function (el) {
        return el != "";
      }));
    });    
  });
  
  importRangeFormulae = importRangeFormulae.flat(2);
  
  importRangeFormulae = importRangeFormulae.filter(function (formula) {
    if (formula.toLowerCase().includes("importrange")) {
      return formula;
    }
  });
  
  DriveApp.createFile("Import Formulae from Master Sheet.txt", importRangeFormulae.toString());
}
```

Comment: Hey Rafa, It's super useful. Pardon on my English skills, My questions is that how can I know how many sheets are linked to my Master sheet and which sheet (links) are pulling the data from my Master Sheet. Is there any way to get those links or count of sheets which are connected via Importarange using script or any other means?

Comment: The links are all in the file created by `DriveApp`, called `Import Formulae from Master Sheet.txt`. You can get the Spreadsheet links directly from this file. Also, the number of spreadsheets linked would be the number of unique file IDs in the returned array.